# Bash script to find .jpgs created within a certain time frame and then rename them

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following `find` command working pretty well which walks through a directory tree looking for any .jpg it finds with a file modification date of 600 minutes or less:

```
find /some/directory/ -depth -mmin -600 -name *.jpg
```

What I need to do now is rename all the .jpg it finds to the actual creation date that the .jpg was created on and create some random numbers at the end of the file before appending `.jpg` back to it.  I've used this in the past: `(date -r "$f" +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%N).jpg` but I can't seem to figure out how to tie the `find` to the `mv`.

Am I missing a simple way to do this with `-exec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
find /some/directory/ -depth -mmin -600 -name "*.jpg" \
    -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(date -r "$1" +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-)$(date +%N).jpg"' bash {} \;
```

Remove `echo` to do renaming once you are satisfied with result.

Comment: `the original location after the rename` so copy instead of move...

Comment: @Philippe That did it!  I wish I could award the answer to both of you guys!